# Как записывать данные в модель с абстрактной моделью?

Tags: python, django

У меня есть модель, которая наследует абстрактную модель. Как мне правильно отправить запрос на добавление данных в БД через Django ORM?

Comment: Не могли бы вы добавить код модели, которая наследует абстрактную модель? (Кнопка "Править")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Точно так же как если бы работали с обычной моделью. Просто помните, что помимо полей и методов указанных в вашей модели, есть еще и методы и поля из абстрактной.

Поля и методы основной модели переопределяют поля и методы абстрактной

---

PS: Какой вопрос - такой ответ :)

PSS: Добавляйте хоть какой то кусок кода